# Shapefile being read incorrectly while trying to plot spatial object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, shapefile

I'm new to geo spatial analysis, and am having trouble reading my SHP file correctly when trying to do overlay plots with ggplot2.

For example, if I use the .shp file from http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip

And read my data using `readOGR()` from the `rgdal` package

```
shape_x <- readOGR("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")
```

I can draw the following using base R

```
plot(shape_x)
```

[image]

But when I try using `ggplot`, I get something funky:

```
ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data=as.data.frame(shape_x), aes(shape_x$LON, shape_x$LAT),
             fill="white", colour="black")
```

[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I'm not sure how to specify the correct xy coordinates in `aes()` in `geom_polygon()`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://r-charts.com/spatial/maps-ggplot2/

Comment: Hi Phil, is there a way that I can read the xy coordinates correctly into geom_polygon()? Would be keen to understand how the geom_polygon reads the .shp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach using the `sf` package:

```
library(sf)
shape_x <- st_read("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shape_x)
```

[image]
In case you insist to do it with `rgdal` then we have to bring the shape data in a certain form so that ggplot can read it: (we use `broom::tidy` for this):

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)

url <- "http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip"
destfile <- "TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip"
download.file(url, destfile)
unzip(destfile)
shape_x <- readOGR("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")
shape_x_df <- tidy(shape_x)
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = shape_x_df, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               fill = "white", color = "black")
```

[image]